# How Array.join works if separator is an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

i can't understand how Array.join works if separator is an array in Javascript ? I find a detail explanation how it works. My example below

```
arr1 = ['a','b','c'];
arr2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
arr1.join(arr2);

//Output
"ad,e,fbd,e,fc"
```

Comment: Hint 1: what *string* joins all the elements (from arr1)? Hint 2: what happens when an array is coerced into a *string* (eg. "" + arr2)?

Comment: First `arr2` will be converted to a string using `Array.prototype.toString()` and return value (string) will be used to join elements in `arr1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The join method accepts a separator and you're passing an array as separator. So, the join method will first transform it to a string: 'd,e,f'

Thus,

```
ad,e,f
bd,e,f
c // last remains same - no join 
// as you may do like ['a','b','c'].join('-') results a-b-c
```

And final result:

```
ad,e,fbd,e,fc
```

You may read this note on [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#Parameters):

**Separator**

> Specifies a string to separate each pair of adjacent elements of the array. The separator is converted to a string if necessary. If omitted, the array elements are separated with a comma (","). If separator is an empty string, all elements are joined without any characters in between them.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a flexible language. If it will receive something other than it is expecting, it will try to convert the passed value into a form / type that it is expecting.

As from [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), Array's `.join()` method expects a string in argument to be used as a separator for joining array elements. In case you will pass it an array, JavaScript will convert this array into a string internally by calling `.toString()` method of Arrays. And this returned string i.e `d,e,f` will be used as a separator to join elements in outer array.